# Play a music / advertisement when the call is onHold in Android

Tags: android, call

When you place callers on hold. The application should play music / some custom message to the receiver in the background, till the call is in hold. Once the call becomes active, that music / custom message should be stopped. Is there any API's available to do so ?

If so,Please let me know few steps to take it forward.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Android does not allow you to modify the outgoing audio stream during a call. Even though the call is on hold, it is still considered an ongoing call. The best you can do is to play whatever you want to over the loudspeaker and hope the microphone picks it up.

Comment: Hi Raghav, Could you please share some more points in this statement."The best you can do is to play whatever you want to over the loudspeaker and hope the microphone picks it up."

Comment: @NandagopalT I'm saying that the only way to do what you want is to have the sound being played loud enough for the phone's mic to pick up. However, this will not work when the call is on hold, as the mic is disabled for that call. It will work during a normal call, assuming you play it loud enough

Comment: Oh.. Thanks Raghav. Is there any possibility this can be done using SIP ? I saw few routines like isOnHold, Will that be useful for implementing this feature.

Comment: That will only tell you when the call is on hold. It still won't allow you to play an arbitrary audio stream over it. In short, you cannot achieve this on stock Android.

Comment: Raghav, I have one more query to discuss, The android system doesn't allows the to play a arbitary audio stream. That is a valid one. But while i make a call to be on hold, the receiver on the other end hears some message / music by the providers, right ?. Could be share your views on this please ?

Comment: @NandagopalT That message/music is coming from the provider, and not from your device.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22883/discussion-between-nandagopal-t-and-raghav-sood)